# Error en consulta mysqli_query

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Envio por medio de ajax la consulta como cadena, pero al momento de ejecutarla con `mysqli_query`, me da el siguiente error.

```
" SELECT * FROM mt4history where (ordertype <= 1) AND symbol != 'archived' AND symbol IN ('EURJPY','EURUSD')" data-journal.js:317:10
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'null' at line 1

Anteriormente lo quise hacer con `mysql` pero encontre que estaba decrepado y me daban otros errores.

Este es mi codigo php donde recibo la cadena

```
elseif ($eks=="detailfilter") {
     
    $jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $phpObject = json_decode($jsonString);
    
    $newJsonString = json_encode($phpObject);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
     
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $newJsonString);
    if(!$result){
        die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($rowCatData = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo $rowCatData;
        }
    }
    
    mysqli_close($con);
    
       }
```

Tambien lo que hice fue hacer la prueba directa de la siguiente manera

```
elseif ($eks=="detailfilter") {

$query = "SELECT * FROM mt4history where (ordertype <= 1) AND symbol != 'archived' AND symbol IN ('EURJPY')";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(!$result){
    die(mysqli_error($con));
}


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($rowCatData = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $rowCatData;
    }
}


mysqli_close($con);

   }
```

Esa consulta la estoy realizando en phpMyAdmin y si me funciona.
[image: La consulta en phpMyAdmin si me esta funcionando]

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * FROM mt4history where  symbol IN ('EURJPY','EURUSD')"' at line 1`                                        

Es el error que me da en postman

Comment: Hace falta más código del contexto en que ocurre en el error. Habla de que algo es `null` pero en lo que muestras no se maneja nada que pueda ser `null`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Agregue el codigo php donde estoy realizando la consulta a la base de datos

Comment: ¿No será más bien este el problema: `$newJsonString`? ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($newJsonString);` puesto en el primer bloque de código que hay en la pregunta?

Comment: `string(62) ""SELECT * FROM mt4history where symbol IN ('EURJPY','EURUSD')""
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * FROM mt4history where symbol IN ('EURJPY','EURUSD')"' at line 1`
Eso es lo que regresa el var_dum($newJsonString);

Comment: Si observas, la salida del `var_dump` no coincide con la consulta que se supone debería crearse según planteas en la pregunta. Por otro lado, el `var_dump` dice que la cadena `SELECT * FROM mt4history where symbol IN ('EURJPY','EURUSD')` tiene 62 caracteres cuando tiene 61 en realidad, puede que en el JSON se esté escapando algún carácter que esté ocasionando el error de sintaxis. ¿Qué muestra un `var_ dump($jsonString);` y un `var_dump($phpObject);`?

Comment: `string(83) "

       "SELECT * FROM mt4history where symbol IN ('EURJPY','EURUSD')"
      
"
string(60) "SELECT * FROM mt4history where symbol IN ('EURJPY','EURUSD')"`

Es lo que muestran los dos var_dump respectivamente

Comment: Tenemos dos consultas, tenemos espacios en blanco y tenemos quién sabe qué más... ahí puede haber hasta una bomba programada en bits que puede hacer explotar cualquier sistema... ¿Puedes explicarnos qué es lo que quieres hacer realmente y de dónde vienen esas dos consultas? ¿Puedes explicarnos por qué estás intentando ejecutar consultas ya escritas? ¿Eres consciente del enorme riesgo que eso supone?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138716/discussion-between-jose-lopez-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Quiero hacer filtros con multiselect a una tabla